# View's background not refreshing

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-adapter

I have a custom adapter for a GridView, and I implemented my own selection handling since the custom views absorb the grid's click events. Everything worked fine, but now I want to add functionality for selecting items by code. I wrote a function for this and called it from the activity, but then when the user selects another item, the background for the code selected item (which indicates selection) does not get updated! I tried calling postInvalidate, but that didn't have any effect. Here's the adapter's code:

```
class PaintActionsAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private Context context;
private View[] listItemsViews;
private OnListItemClickListener itemClickListener;
private int[] actionsImagesResources;
private int lastSelectedPosition=-1;
private int pendingSelectedPosition=-1;

private class ActionButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private int position;

    public ActionButtonClickListener(int position)
    { this.position=position; }

    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        changeSelectedListItem(position);
        if (itemClickListener!=null)
            itemClickListener.onListItemClick(view,position);
    }
}

public PaintActionsAdapter(Context context,OnListItemClickListener 
        itemClickListener)
{
    if (context==null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The context must be non-null!");
    this.context=context;
    this.itemClickListener=itemClickListener;
    TypedArray imagesResourcesNames=context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(
            R.array.actions_images);
    actionsImagesResources=new int[imagesResourcesNames.length()];
    for (int counter=0;counter<actionsImagesResources.length;counter++)
    {
        actionsImagesResources[counter]=imagesResourcesNames.getResourceId(
                counter,-1);
    }
    imagesResourcesNames.recycle();
    listItemsViews=new View[actionsImagesResources.length];
}

public int getCount() { return actionsImagesResources.length; }
public long getItemId(int position)
{ return actionsImagesResources[position]; }
public Object getItem(int position) 
{ return actionsImagesResources[position]; }

public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
{
    ImageView actionImageView;
    if (convertView==null)
    {
        actionImageView=new ImageView(context);
        /*actionToggleButton=new ToggleButton(context);
        actionToggleButton.setTextOn(null);
        actionToggleButton.setTextOff(null);
        actionToggleButton.setText(null);*/
        AbsListView.LayoutParams layoutParams=new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.
                WRAP_CONTENT);
        actionImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }
    else actionImageView=(ImageView)convertView;
    actionImageView.setImageResource(actionsImagesResources[position]);
    actionImageView.setOnClickListener(new ActionButtonClickListener(position));
    listItemsViews[position]=actionImageView;
    if (pendingSelectedPosition==position)
    {
        changeSelectedListItem(position);
        pendingSelectedPosition=-1;
    }
    return actionImageView;
}

public void setSelectedListItem(int position)
{
    if ((position<0)||(position>actionsImagesResources.length))
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("The position of the list " +
                "item to select must be between 0 and " + actionsImagesResources.
                length + "! The value supplied was " + position);
    if (listItemsViews[position]==null) pendingSelectedPosition=position;
    else changeSelectedListItem(position);
}

private void changeSelectedListItem(int position)
{
    listItemsViews[position].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.
            actions_list_selector);
    if (lastSelectedPosition>-1) 
    {
        listItemsViews[lastSelectedPosition].setBackgroundResource(0);
        listItemsViews[lastSelectedPosition].postInvalidate();
    }
    lastSelectedPosition=position;
}
}
```

The function setSelectedListItem lets the activity change the selection, and calls changeSelectedListItem, which uses setBackgroundResource(0) to remove the selection indication from the last selected item. This works perfectly when the user selects the item by clicking it, but not if the selection of the last item was done through setSelectedListItem.

I hope I explained the issue clearly, and any help will be appreciated.